# How to calculate "hot" or "interesting" data? Based on both the rating and the number of ratings.

Tags: data-analysis, sorting

I can't be the first to ask this but I have now idea how to word my question correctly. I tried googling but was not successful.

Let's say I have an excel sheet with names of applications. Each row contains, aside from the app name,

1. What rating the application has on an app store (0-100 %)
2. How many people rated the app

I want to calculate some kind of "hotness" or "popularity" score and sort the apps by this score.
I can't just sort them by the rating, because apps that only have 1 rating of 100% would rise to the top, which I don't want. Similarly, if I sort just by the number of rating, bad apps with a lot of rating would rise to the top. I'm interested in seeing apps that are both well rated and have a lot of ratings at the top and the ones that are bad rated or don't have many ratings at the bottom.

I really think this is quite an intuitive question and many people must have encountered this problem. How would I go about solving this? Is there some generally accepted solution? Is there some terminology that I missing that I can google?

Comment: So you want to go to the restaurant such that the probability of having the best meal is maximised, if we treat the reviews as objective judgements of the food, service etc. That's actually an interesting mathematical question. And even if the best restaurant based on your algorithm is a seafood restaurant and you don't like seafood, you can just scroll down the list produced by your algorithm until you find the restaurant you want to go to. And so listing restaurants in this way is *useful* if all you care about are ratings.

Comment: They probably do lists like this *already* (although it's not this simple: restaurants probably pay TripAdvisor to artificially get to the top of the list, and there's other factors like distance from your current location to the restaurant that are factored into the equation). But to get a  better feel for these real-world algorithms, I don't think math.stackexchange is the best place. However, if you want to answer the mathematical probability question where the only two factors are "ratings" and "number of reviews", then that can be answered for you here.

Comment: I never tried to solve this problem personally but central limit theory might help you. Assume that rating pattern of an individual is Gaussian with some deviation. (It usually isn't, people are more inclined to give 1s and 5s out of 5.) Then, you can calculate the differential entropy of the pattern. The lower the diff. entropy, the more accurate the rating will be.